# Extract files from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a dictionary with a string and a file (can be a png or recording).
I have to extract them, and I am doing it in this way:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:context];
NSString *Name = [[myDictionary objectForKey:@"fileName"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSData *File = [[myDictionary objectForKey:@"FileData"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

But the app crashes at NSString *Name = [[myDictionary objectForKey:@"fileName"] objectAtIndex:0];. Is this right?

Comment: What is the exception?  Have you done `po myDictionary` to see the contents?

Comment: NSLog myDictionary to see what it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the following to get the data out of `myDictionary`:

```
NSString *Name = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"fileName"];
NSData *File = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"FileData"];
```

You dont need the objectAtIndex:0 wrapper unless it is a level down.

It is usually NSArray (or NSMutableArray) that use objectAtIndex as arrays use an index not keys. Dictionaries use objectForKey